# Are logical pixels the units returned by the dx property of the Offset class?

Tags: flutter

Does the dx property of the [Offset](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Offset-class.html) class return the double value of the logical pixels on the x-axis? I need to know if I can measure say a percentage of the dx against MediaQuery.of(context).size.width?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: The dx property of an Offset object and the Width size of a Media Query are both doubles (pixel, yes) thus you can divide, multiply or do any math operation with them (separately or with each other). So, you can do your **OffsetObject.dx/MediaQuery(context).Size.Width** to get the percentage. You can run the code block below on Dart pad.

**Loooong Answer**: Not sure it adds more info.

- Yes, of course you can measure the dx property of an Offset object against the width property of a MediaQuery because they are both of type double.
- The mere fact that they are both of type doubles should allow you to carry out any math/arithmetic calculation you need. **See the sample app below.** the text returns the numbers (you can run it on Dartpad). I explained the variables/objects defined below as well.
- **ScreenWidthSize**: the MediaQuery width, note the type is double. MediaQuery.of(context).size.width returns an object of type double.
- **offsetMagnitude**: This defines the Offset object (I am not sure how you will get your Offset object so this for illustration. Then I need to get the dx.
- **horizontalOffset**: This defines/extracts the dx property of the **offsetMagnitude**, the offset object. Note it is a double too.
- **horizontalOffsetToScreenWidthRatio**: Since both **ScreenWidthSize** and **horizontalOffset** are doubles, I can carry out any mathematical operation, as long as they are applicable to the type double. I have therefore measured the percentage (we can format the result better but you get it).

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidthSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    Offset offsetMagnitude = Offset(12,25);
    double horizontalOffset = offsetMagnitude.dx;
 
    double horizontalOffsetToScreenWidthRatio = offsetMagnitude.dx/screenWidthSize;

    return Text(
      'Hello, my screen is $screenWidthSize wide and my horizontal offset is $horizontalOffset, so the horizontal offset to screen width ratio is $horizontalOffsetToScreenWidthRatio',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
    );
  }
}

/* Not sure what you are trying to achieve but it seems like some form of adaptive or responsive operation. I think if you check the docs, you will find a close widget needing only little manipulation to achieve what you want. Check the Align widget, might be what you need*/
```

Comment: I understand that they are both doubles. I would like to know the conceptual units that their double values represent. Is it the number of logical pixels from point (0, 0)? I might need to test this out with a full screen application. If the max Offset.dx I can use without overflowing is equal to MediaQuery.size, then I will be sure they are logical pixels from (0,0)